# cscope-minor-mode not enabled for C in emacs 25

Tags: minor-mode, c

I'm using Emacs 25 on Ubuntu 16.04, after a while spent on Emacs 24. One thing that I've noticed changed in version 25 is, cscope minor mode is not enabled by default when I edit C files, while it was in Emacs 24 (I also checked that this is the case with `C-h m`, `cscope` is indeed present in 24 but not 25). I'm using `xcscope-el` that comes with Ubuntu 16.04 (version 1.1-1, as far as I can tell). I have to type `M-x cscope-minor-mode` whenever opening a C file, which is quite annoying.

I have very limited knowledge of Elisp and don't understand how minor modes are associated with major ones, any idea what's going on here, or how can I at least start to investigate why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving contents of my comment to answer:
Thanks, got some help on the Emacs help group: groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gnu.emacs.help/7U816OSm2Cw Apparently, adding (cscope-setup) in my .emacs solved it. Still not sure why this worked automagically in 24. That function adds hooks for a bunch of languages, including C and C++.

Comment: I missed this the first time I scanned/read it.  The key is `(cscope-setup)`.

Answer (score 0):

Even my knowledge is limited, but I could do it by adding following line to my .emacs

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook (lambda () (interactive) (setq cscope-minor-mode t)))
```

You can add hooks for other languages also.

Comment: Hook functions don't need to be interactive.  And minor modes are better enabled by calling their function.  I.e.:  `(add-hook 'c-mode-hook #'cscope-minor-mode)`

Comment: @fencekicker Please write your last comment as an answer to your own question **and accept it as soon as possible**. If you remove your comment afterwards I will do the same.

Comment: @Tobias OK, I just did that.